# How to synchronize Azure Active Directory User that is given a CRM License to Dynamics 365 Online

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-365

My understanding regarding the synchronization are as follows:

1. Create Member User in Active Directory
2. Assign CRM License in Active Directory
3. User will be created in Dynamics CRM

However, I'm not sure when will point no 3 is triggered.

Should the new member user login for the first time inside the CRM to change password for it to be created in CRM? (This is the behavior that I observed)

Or will it auto synchronized after some time?

Comment: Synchronization to Dynamics 365 / Dataverse can take some hours to take effect.

Comment: Is there any docs link which gives us the frequency of this sync ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Henk van Boeijen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3190732/henk-van-boeijen) for your comment adding more to your comment to make it as answer and understandable to other users.

**The below answer is publish by soundharya subhash under Power Platform Learning**

When an new Environment is created, it takes more than an hour or some times a day to sync users from Azure AD to CRM.

Through Power Shell cmdlets, we can sync user immediately.

Install Module

[Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/?view=pa-ps-latest)

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell
```

Connect to Power Apps using any of these

User Name and Password

```
Add-PowerAppsAccount -Endpoint “prod” -Username “” -Password “”
```

Tenant Id, Client Id and Client Secret

```
Add-PowerAppsAccount -Endpoint “prod” -TenantID “” -ClientSecret “” `
-ApplicationId “”
```

Tenant Id, Client ID and Certificate Thumbprint

```
Add-PowerAppsAccount -Endpoint “prod” -TenantID “” -CertificateThumbprint “” `
-ApplicationId "

"
```

**Get-AdminPowerAppEnvironment** cmdlet gives list of environments available in Tenant, note down the environment name (guid) to which you want to sync the Users

Go to Azure Portal : https://portal.azure.com -> Azure AD -> Users -> note down the Object Id of the user you want to sync

Run the cmdlet in Power Shell

```
Add-AdminPowerAppsSyncUser -EnvironmentName <Guid> -PrincipalObjectId…
```

Reference : https://nishantrana.me/2021/01/20/force-sync-users-from-azure-ad-to-dynamics-crm/